# Multiline If statement with a single conditional

Tags: python, pep8

Lets say I have two variables

```
self.SuperLongSpecificCorperateVariableNameIcantChangeCommunication
```

and

```
self.SuperLongSpecificCorperateVariableNameIcantChangeControl
```

And I need to compare them.

The issue being that, when I put them both in an if statement, it blows past the style checker's line length.

```
if (self.SuperLongSpecificCorperateVariableNameIcantChangeCommunication != self.SuperLongSpecificCorperateVariableNameIcantChangeControl):
```

The way around this would be to split this into two lines.

```
if (self.SuperLongSpecificCorperateVariableNameIcantChangeCommunication \
    != self.SuperLongSpecificCorperateVariableNameIcantChangeControl):
```

My coworkers are split on whether PEP 8 has you split between conditionals or whether you can split up a conditional itself. Ideally we would get approval to change the variable name, but in the meantime, what does PEP 8 say we should do in this case?

Comment: Definitely split, much easier to read

Comment: You don't need the backslash. The parentheses suffice.

Comment: I dont see any issue in spliting it

Comment: What does Black say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, PEP 8 says you can split long lines under [Maximum Line Length](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length):

> Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.

In fact, the backslash in your example is not needed because of the parentheses.

---

PEP 8 says you can split a conditional under [multiline if-statements](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#multiline-if-statements), although the main focus of that section is how to distinguish it from the following block.

> When the conditional part of an `if`-statement is long enough to require that it be written across multiple lines, it's worth noting that the combination of a two character keyword (i.e. `if`), plus a single space, plus an opening parenthesis creates a natural 4-space indent for the subsequent lines of the multiline conditional. This can produce a visual conflict with the indented suite of code nested inside the `if`-statement, which would also naturally be indented to 4 spaces. This PEP takes no explicit position on how (or whether) to further visually distinguish such conditional lines from the nested suite inside the `if`-statement. Acceptable options in this situation include, but are not limited to:
>
> ```
> # No extra indentation.
> if (this_is_one_thing and
>     that_is_another_thing):
>     do_something()
>
> # Add a comment, which will provide some distinction in editors
> # supporting syntax highlighting.
> if (this_is_one_thing and
>     that_is_another_thing):
>     # Since both conditions are true, we can frobnicate.
>     do_something()
>
> # Add some extra indentation on the conditional continuation line.
> if (this_is_one_thing
>         and that_is_another_thing):
>     do_something()
> ```

Personally, I would go for the last option for maximum readability. So that gives us:

```
if (self.SuperLongSpecificCorperateVariableNameIcantChangeCommunication
        != self.SuperLongSpecificCorperateVariableNameIcantChangeControl):
    do_something()
```

### Other options

You could use temporary "internal use" names to shorten the line:

```
_Comm = self.SuperLongSpecificCorperateVariableNameIcantChangeCommunication
_Control = self.SuperLongSpecificCorperateVariableNameIcantChangeControl
if _Comm != _Control:
    do_something()
```

This is assuming the context is not in a local scope. If it is actually in a local scope, they don't need to be "internal use".

---

You could use a helper function to give them shorter names in a local scope. Since they're attributes, you can pass in their object:

```
def _compare(instance):
    a = instance.SuperLongSpecificCorperateVariableNameIcantChangeCommunication
    b = instance.SuperLongSpecificCorperateVariableNameIcantChangeControl
    return a != b

if _compare(self):
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 5):

According to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length):

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied
> line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. ***Long lines
> can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in
> parentheses***. These should be used ***in preference to using a backslash***
> for line continuation.

There is also a discussion about [multiline if-statements](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#multiline-if-statements) which doesn't take an explicit position but recommends to add an indentation level to the conditional's continuation line.

Lastly, [Should a Line Break Before or After a Binary Operator?](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id20) recommends to break ***before*** the operator (as you did). So you could write:

```py
if (self.SuperLongSpecificCorperateVariableNameIcantChangeCommunication
        != self.SuperLongSpecificCorperateVariableNameIcantChangeControl):
    pass
```

But variables in Python are just names - a way to reference an object. Names can be changed. Line breaks can be avoided:

```py
communication = self.SuperLongSpecificCorperateVariableNameIcantChangeCommunication 
control = self.SuperLongSpecificCorperateVariableNameIcantChangeControl 

if communication != control:
    pass
```